# What tag is better: limited-liability-company or llc

Tags: discussion, tagging

We have both [llc](/questions/tagged/llc) and [limited-liability-company](/questions/tagged/limited-liability-company) tags currently.   I'm not sure which we should keep.

I think most people refer to an LLC by the initials.

I do think that whichever way we decide, lets create a tag synonym to the "winner" so that it automatically gets renamed.

Thoughts on llc vs limited-liability-company tags?

Comment: TLAs: gotta love 'em! Related: I wanted to create a tag "required-minimum-distribution", but, IIRC, it exceeded the maximum tag length, so we ended up with "rmd" instead.  I wonder what that may collide with down the road.

Answer (score 6):

In the UK, LLC isn't a standard acronym (limited companies are either "ltd" or "plc" depending on some other factors I forget). So I think I'd prefer limited-liability-company.

Comment: I hadn't considered the concept of LLC expanding beyond the united state.  I'm going to go [vote for the tag synonym](http://money.stackexchange.com/tags/limited-liability-company/synonyms) so "llc" gets renamed to "limited-liability-company" automatically.

Comment: Agreed, most countries have a concept of "limited liability company" in law but have little agreement about what to call such a vehicle.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for.... (Rips 'S' From Chest) ... [Tag Synonyms](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/tag-folksonomy-and-tag-synonyms/)!

I added it, and you can vote on it [here](https://money.stackexchange.com/tags/limited-liability-company/synonyms).

Comment: So you propose that limited-liability-company is more correct based on your synonym, right?

Comment: It wouldn't let me do it that way because there were more questions already tagged with the spelled out version.

Answer (score 1):

I'll vote for `llc`.   I think that people refer to the entity as a "llc" and not as a limited liability company.

[Google search stats](http://www.googlefight.com/index.php?lang=en_GB&word1=limited+liability+company&word2=llc): llc 48M hits, limited liability company 1.8M hits

Comment: As far the question is concerned, LLC is used more often and so IMO that should likely be the main tag.  That said, "limited liability company" is more *correct*  -- as LLC is an acronym for it -- though not necessarily as a tag. :)

Comment: I agree and tried to create it that way, but the system won't allow it because the spelled out version has already been used on more questions.

Comment: I disagree if you look at it from a non-us centric point of view. Yes, most people in the US will know what an LLC is, but it's not necessarily an expression that's very familiar to people in other English speaking countries (see Ganesh's answer, for example).

Comment: @timo Which would you say is used more often in those countries, the acronym or the fully spelled out term?

Comment: @George speaking just for the UK, neither is normally used, but at least the fully spelled out term would be understandable.

Comment: @ganesh Neither is LLC a widely used term in the US.  However, that is not the question that I asked.

Comment: @george, in the UK the acronym that would be used for the US equivalent of an LLC would be 'LTD'. People are using the term 'limited company' instead of 'limited liability company' if they're talking about company formation etc but I would think that 'limited liability company' will be understood whereas LLC most like won't.

Comment: @timo I was trying to determine if the primary concern was whether the average person would understand the acronym or whether the professionals/enthusiasts from one region would understand the acronym of another region.  It seems to be the former, which would make me lean towards using the fully spelled term as the main tag, just to make it easier for new users.  That said, now that tags can be documented it is almost a moot point.  One should not have much trouble clicking on a tag in order to access the documentation.